# How can I export a figma file and instantly open it in figma desktop app or browser new tab?

Tags: vue.js, import, export, nuxt.js, figma

I'm using nuxtjs. I have a .fig file and when I will enter any export button it should be open in the desktop app or any browser location like that 'https://www.figma.com/files'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you do allow for a `file.fig` export file in your Nuxt app ? But if you click on the `file.fig`, it does not open ? It's a MIME type issue, not a Nuxt one. And it looks like that working with this kind of file is pretty limited.

Apparently you can only drag-drop the file if you want to open it
[https://spectrum.chat/figma/help/what-is-the-purpose-of-fig-files~cf5cf078-ac34-4290-8687-36423b8572f1](https://spectrum.chat/figma/help/what-is-the-purpose-of-fig-files%7Ecf5cf078-ac34-4290-8687-36423b8572f1)